# Why does StreamReader.readexactly() cause a socket error but not StreamReader.read()?

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I'm writing application in python using Asyncio for networking. I have code similar too:

```
try:
    data = await self._reader.readexactly(10000)

    # Code that uses data
except IncompleteReadError as e:
    data = e.parial
    # More code
```

When I try running this code, it never seems to actually run. If I set a breakpoint on the second line, the breakpoint will trip, but the rest of the function is ignored.

The closest thing I get to an error is this from the asyncio logger:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\Lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 724, in _read_ready
    data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Replacing the second line with `data = await self._reader.read(10000)` appears to solve this issue, but `read()` doesn't solve my issue, I need to use `readexactly()`. So why does `readexactly()` cause a socket error but `read()` not?

Answer (score 0):

the only difference between the two is that "read" read **up** to n bytes while readexactly reads **exactly** n  bytes and if reaches the end before n bytes is raises an **IncompleteReadError** , which may cause your socket to get the error you have pointed out.

Comment: Why isn't the except block run then? The function just terminates completely at that line.

Comment: because you only catch "IncompleteReadError " , try changing that to "Exception" and see if the except block get executed and what is the exception type that get thrown